# Looking for 3D xna engines

Tags: xna

I'm looking for a 3D xna engine that 
1. provides GUI interface for editing games
2. provides Skeleton/rigged animation
3. are Well documented
(in short, engines like Unreal engine)

Comment: I would also like to get some recommendations on available XNA 3D engines and what people think of them. Are there any you are looking at currently?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a *free* engine, I'd suggest that you check out [XNA Final Engine](http://xnafinalengine.codeplex.com).  Also, there is [Ploobs](http://ploobsengine.codeplex.com/).  In fact, here is a large list of engines that are available:

[Synapse Gaming SunBurn Engine 2.0](http://www.synapsegaming.com/) – Nice Game Engine loaded with features and the Best Support & Community Ever

[Digital Rune Engine](http://www.digitalrune.com/Products/GameEngine.aspx) – Great Game Engine  (physics, animation,  math, multi-threading and more)

[Xen Graphics API for XNA](http://xen.codeplex.com/) – rendering tools and much more

[Engine Nine](http://nine.codeplex.com/) – includes, animation, post fx, AI, custom materials, scene management,  deferred lighting and more

[Hilva XNA Graphics Engine](http://www.hilva.com/) – Rendering Engine, Animation, and more

Answer (score 3):

You want SunBurn: http://www.synapsegaming.com/

It runs on WP7, XBOX & Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like [Torque](http://www.torquepowered.com/). It's not a free engine but is know to have quite a advanced toolset.

Comment: It's also not XNA, is it? :-\

Comment: well it supports xna: 
http://www.torquepowered.com/products/consoles
http://www.torquepowered.com/products/torquex-3d/

Answer (score 0):

Of the complete list provided below, only the Engine Nine and Ox Game Engine meet your requirements. If you want something of higher quality the only current choice is [Sunburn](http://www.synapsegaming.com/products/sunburn/engine/) (as mentioned in another answer), which will run you at least $150.

Here's a list of free 3D Game Engines compatible with **XNA 4.0**:

[**QuickStart Engine**](http://quickstartengine.codeplex.com/), uses JigLibX Physics Engine, last updated May 2013, no level editor or animation implemented yet.

[**Axiom3d**](http://axiom3d.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), partial C#/XNA port of Ogre3D, last updated Aug. 2011, no level editor

[**Engine Nine**](http://nine.codeplex.com/), last updated Apr. 2011

---

And older free 3D game engines compatible with **XNA 3.1**:

[**Oops Physics Framework**](http://oopsframework.codeplex.com/), not a complete engine, but includes basic things like a physics engine, terrain, rendering, and input.

[**Ox Game Engine**](http://oxgameengine.codeplex.com/), port of Buttermilk3D engine, last updated Apr. 2010

[**Tomahawk**](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/tomahawkengine)

Answer (score -1):

Well, the top Google result returns [this one and only XNA 3D engine, Reactor 3D](http://www.reactor3d.com/), and [its closure notice](http://www.reactor3d.com/closed.php) pretty much explains why you probably won't find another XNA 3D engine.

**edit**: DevMaster.net just announced a new release of the [Hilva XNA Graphics Engine](http://www.hilva.com/) which appears to be a 3D engine for XNA. However, it seems far from your requirements.